# If logic for value being numeric and greater than zero

Tags: excel, vba

I need help fixing the If logic below:

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Variant
Dim Valid As Boolean
Dim inputDec As Integer

Lastrow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row

While Valid = False
    i = InputBox("Ve kterém sloupci je datum? (A=1,B=2,C=3, atd..)", "Datum")

    If IsNumeric(i) Then
        Valid = True
    Else
        Valid = False
        MsgBox ("Zadejte číslo sloupce! (A=1,B=2,C=3, atd..)")
    End If
Wend
```

You can't enter letters etc..

The problem is, that you can enter < 0.

I tried

```
If IsNumeric(i) And ">0" Then
```

That ended in error.

Comment: `If IsNumeric(i) and i > 0 Then` ?  A little unintuitive, you can't just do `If X is Y and Z`, you have to do `If X is Y and X is Z` (psuedocode, obviously). You have to fully express the condition each time.

Comment: An alternative to forcing the users to enter a number would be to just use the letter (e.g. `Cells(5, "D")` is valid) or, if you really need the column **number**, use something like `Columns("D").Column`.

Answer (score 2):

```
If IsNumeric(i) And i > 0 Then

      Valid = True

Else
   Valid = False
    MsgBox ("Zadejte číslo sloupce! (A=1,B=2,C=3, atd..)")

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here's another way you can tackle this. It doesn't use `Valid` but just checks if `i` matches your criteria, and if it doesn't, it shows the message and asks for an input.:

```
Sub t2()
Dim i As Variant
Dim inputDec As Integer, lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row
i = InputBox("Ve kterém sloupci je datum? (A=1,B=2,C=3, atd..)", "Datum")

Do Until IsNumeric(i) And i > 0
    i = InputBox("Zadejte císlo sloupce! (A=1,B=2,C=3, atd..)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Ve kterém sloupci je datum?", "Datum")
Loop

'Code here will fire when `i` is Numeric and greater than 0
Debug.print "Vstup uživatele: " & i

End Sub
```